# Issue with 3D printer making super thin layers

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3

Recently I've been having trouble printing properly on my Creality Ender-3 printer. I ran a pretty long print (approx. 15 hours) that turned out really well. I then started printing an attachment for the original print and saw that it was printing layers that were extremely thin.

I first scraped off the excess filament left on the extruder nozzle. Then, I heated up the bed and rubbed off the layer with alcohol. I tried printing it again but it still didn't print right.

Thin layer
[image: Thin layer]

Weird thing
[image: Weird thing]

From the images above, you can tell it's noticeably hard to see the layer, which shows just how thin it is.

I sliced the model in Ultimaker Cura. I set the layer height to 0.15 mm. I've printed models before with this height but the layer wasn't transparent.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Check your bed height. The bed is probably too close to the nozzle.

Comment: Wait, what? Can you give me a quick walkthrough on how?

Comment: There should be a good canonical question/answer on bed leveling but I don't know how to find it easily. Stick around and see if someone else can.

Comment: 2 Things: first of all you want to level your bed to about a paper thickness from the nozzle in "0" position. Then, check your first layer thickness. I have set mine to always be 0.2 mm, which does aleviate problems with slight inconsistencies in the bed (like slight bends or kinks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to level you bed.  Thin prints happen when the extruder is too low and is printing too close to the bed.

[image: Example of printing levels]

Download the following test codes from this address:

https://www.chepclub.com/bed-level.html

1) The first code is the most important you will want to run moves the extruder to five points on your board - Front Left and Right, Back Left and Right, and Center.  Using a folded piece of paper - I use a business card - drag the paper under extruder of each of the four corners.  You want to make sure you get a bit of drag when pulling out the paper/card.  If you feel have enough of a gap that you can run put the paper/card under the extruder and that you feel a bit of tug when pulling it out.  It runs the middle last - if you are having issue with the drag, adjust all four corners slowly until it is right.

2) The second runs the extruder in a square pattern on your board.  You simply want to run your finger of the print - if it sticks to the bed, you are good - if it doesn't, adjust your corners up and keep testing.

Answer (score 4):

If your first layer is more thin than you expect it to be, the bed is too close to the nozzle. Note that you need to check the level an bed-to-nozzle distance once every few prints. Also, the first layer shouldn't be a too thin layer, the Cura default for a 0.4 mm nozzle is about 0.28 mm. Personally, I always use 0.2 mm.

The best solution is to re-slice the model with a thicker first layer. Next, re-level the bed to the proper distance of an A4/US Letter printing paper. You should feel some drag when you pull it between nozzle and bed.

Other solutions that also work include the redefinition of the Z=0 level, but this is not advised. Please fix the hardware.